# MD5 hash of original Windows 8 pro iso file

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, md5sum

What is the MD5 hash of the original Win 8 Professional ISO (upgrade version)? I downloaded the file over multiple download sessions, and want to make sure that the file is not corrupted.

Does the download program automatically verify the file, before prompting to install / create installation media?

**Update** : I went ahead and installed. Fortunately, the installation went smoothly.

Comment: The website didn't include a tiny file to verify the CRC or MD5 hash with? Weird.

Comment: The file was not downloaded directly from the website. It is with the Windows 8 upgrade application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows8-UpdateAssistant/Windows8-Setup programs download the files into C:\ESD\Windows. Most of the files in there have a file-date of 26-July-2012, but install.esd and boot.wim have a file-date of the download date. So I wonder whether they are especially made for you. If they are, there wont be a single value MD5 hash for the ISO, because the ISO is created from those files.

I had to download the files three times before I got a version that worked. So even though there is some verification process, it doesn't seem to work very well.

In the first two attempts I created a USB boot device but during setup I got an 0x8007025D error. I tried the same files to create an ISO to use in a VM, same problem.

After the third download it worked in a VM, but not with a USB device on a real machine. I tried a different USB device and finally got it to work.

Comment: Are install.esd and boot.win present in the iso file?

Comment: Yes and they are very important for the install.

Comment: "So I wonder whether they are especially made for you." - Precisely [what I wanted to know](http://superuser.com/questions/493780/queries-related-to-windows-8-upgrade-installation-media) as well!