# Can I use the W8 upgrade download to install in BootCamp/Parallels/VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-8, virtualization, boot-camp, parallels, windows-8-upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If I’m performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers)
>   [How hard is it to upgrade my Boot Camp Windows 7 to Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/494384/how-hard-is-it-to-upgrade-my-boot-camp-windows-7-to-windows-8)

MS is offering heavily discounted W8 upgrade by download currently. I want to run a single Windows installation on my Mac using either BootCamp or virtualization (probably Parallels). I currently don't have an earlier Windows BootCamp/VM installed, but I do have a license to do so.

My question is: can I buy and download the W8 upgrade file on another PC and use it to get Windows 8 on the Mac at a later date?

As a side question: would I have to install W7 on the Mac and upgrade it?

Comment: Also see: [If I'm performing a an upgrade to Windows 8, do I have to have the previous version installed, or is just having the key enough?](http://superuser.com/questions/493586/if-im-performing-a-an-upgrade-to-windows-8-do-i-have-to-have-the-previous-vers?lq=1) and [Queries related to Windows 8 Upgrade installation media](http://superuser.com/questions/493780/queries-related-to-windows-8-upgrade-installation-media)

Answer (score 0):

Can you physically do it?
Possibly maybe, never tried.

Are you legally allowed to?
No.  The EULA that you agree to when purchasing the upgrade explicitly states that the upgrade is for an already licenced and eligible OS such as XP, Vista or Win 7.  The licence is for an upgrade and not a "new" install.  A license for the older version should effectively vanish when using the "upgrade" license.

I don't know if or how Microsoft would or could police this but what you are proposing is precisely against the terms of your purchase agreement with Microsoft.

Comment: So if I have a valid W7 license, I have to physically install it and then install W8 over the top? Couldn't it be argued I am still upgrading W7 to W8 even if W7 isn't installed?

Comment: If you have a valid Windows 7 license then legally you must stop using that license for the upgrade to be valid.  It doesn't have to be over the top, but one license is (in the lawyers and Microsoft's eyes) invalidated by using the other.  If you *had* a valid W7 license that you no longer use then you can rightfully upgrade that to W8, but you should not be using the W7 license.  Note that an OEM license as supplied by Dell or others cannot be transferred to another machine so you would not have a "valid" W8 license unless you upgraded a Retail W7 license.

Comment: The only way an OEM license can be upgraded is by installing it on the machine that "owns" the W7 licence, that machine should have an OEM license sticker on it.

Comment: That would be fine I guess, I get I am effectively invalidating the old license legally.